# Magento 2: Server error (5xx)

Tags: magento2.3, server-setup, http-error-500, mobile-device, webserver

Google Search Console notifies an error as shown in the screenshot. How to ensure such errors do not occur so the search engines can crawl and access the pages on the site?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check var/logs folder in your magento root directory and check for exceptions in th exceptions file for sure those 500 errors are somethings from your server ( maybe php syntax error ) or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to check in the folder you specified.

Comment: exceptions.log is empty, and in the Google Search Console, 500 error is moved under N/A validation column with 0 affected pages. Do you think this error might have got auto-solved or something?

Comment: it might be a load problem, like lot of requests sent and overloaded the system, do you own the system? 
is there any apache error log files?
can you check /var/log and/or /var/log/apache ( system files not in magento root )

Comment: No apache error log files. There are many log files under var/log such as system.log, debug,cron, exception.log, setup.log

Comment: Any more possible solutions?